# video not found on details view asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access a specific video through it's ID in a details view I keep getting a 404 error but the video is accessible on the index view. I have no idea why this is happening but the filepath is valid in the index. I inspected the link i get in the details view and it looks right to me I get the same relative link I got in the index view.

my details action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
if (movie == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(movie);
```

my detail view:

```
    @model MvcMovie.Models.Movie
    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }
    <h2>Details</h2>
    <div>
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <div class="row">
    <hr />
    <!--Main video-->
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <video id="video" poster="~/Images/algo.jpg" controls="controls" 
             loop="loop" style="width:750px; height:350px;">
            <source src="@Url.Content(Model.VideoFilePath)" 
             type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </dt>
            @*Markup omitted for clarity.*@
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                Photo
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <img src="@Model.PosterFilePath" alt="Avatar" 
                style="height:300px;width:200px;" />

            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Genre)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
            </dd>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rating)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <!--End Main video-->
```

Index action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
    {
        var GenreLst = new List<string>();

        var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                       orderby d.Genre
                       select d.Genre;

        GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

        var movies = from m in db.Movies
                     select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
        }

        return View("Index",movies);
    }
```

index view:

```
       @model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
       @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }
       <h2>All Movies</h2>
       <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
        {
          <p class="text-center">
           Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")
           Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
           <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </p>
         }
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">

            <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"  
             src='@item.PosterFilePath'alt="thumbnail" />

            <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</strong>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            <br>
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            </strong>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
            <br>
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)</strong>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            <br>
            <strong> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</strong>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            <br>
            <strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)</strong>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
            <br>
            <div class="">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-
                 toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax@(item.ID)">Watch 
                 now</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"><span 
                 class="glyphicon-download"></span>Download</button>
            </div>

            <br>

            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })

        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="ajax@(item.ID)">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-
                          dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                       <h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <video id="video" poster="~/Images/algo.jpg"
                               controls="controls"
                               loop="loop"
                               width="535"
                               height="350">
                            <source src="@Url.Content(item.VideoFilePath)" 
                             type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-
                        primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon-folder-close">
                        </span>Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn -
                        success">Download</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Movie movie = db.Movies.Where(x=>x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It did not work but it is not incorrect. thank you for answering

Comment: @Khanyisa Fante, please provide your index View and Controller code

Comment: @Khanyisa Fante, your problem in that <video id="video" poster="~/Images/algo.jpg" controls="controls" 
             loop="loop" style="width:750px; height:350px;">
            <source src="@Url.Content(Model.VideoFilePath)" 
             type="video/mp4">
        </video> not showing video?

Comment: yes I get 404 not found on details view but it works on index view

Comment: @Khanyisa Fante, please provide your index View and Controller code

Comment: upon further inspection of the link in the details view video there is a difference in the details view the link is localhost:2235/movies/uploads/movies/moviename.mp4 whereas in index it is localhost:2235/uploads/movies/moviename.mp4

Comment: so you find problem by your self, replace @Url.Content to reletive path "~/@(Model.VideoFilePath)"

Comment: can you tell me why it appended the movies file to the link when I used url.content?

Comment: Oh, i think i got it. When you go to the Index method you get url like localhost/ControllerName  because of route config that specify index as default method and when you get to Details method you get url like this localhost/ControllerName/MethodName and @Url.Content gets incorect relative path. Try to open your index method with full path localhost/Movies/Index than i think you get same problem.